# How to remove ria services from wcf service

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services

I have a plain old wcf service that I tried to deploy to my hosting service.  When I try to access my service on the remote server I get "Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting'"  I searched my project for any references to that .dll (and system.web.ria) and there are none, which I believe is correct.  To be clear, I never tried to configure my wcf service to use ria, so I don't know how my project even knows such a thing exists.

I have a silverlight client that accesses this service but I do not (intentionally) use RIA services on the client or the server.  My service is (or should be) plain old wcf - I generate client side proxies using slsvcutil and it works fine on my development machine.

Do I need RIA services to access my wcf service with silverlight?  How do I get rid of this error without deploying ria services?  I do not want to use ria services unless I have too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need RIA Services to access wcf service with Silverlight. Check your solution again. But, for getting rid of this error without installing ria services on the server,

If you are using the Visual Studio Build->Publish option to deploy your application, make sure the `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting` assembly under the Web Application->References have been marked as **Copy Local = True**

If you are copying the bits over manually to your deployment server, copy the above assembly to the Web Applications BIN folder right next to your `[WebAppName].dll`

according http://blogs.msdn.com/saurabh/archive/2010/03/16/ria-services-application-deployment.aspx